# Как проверить есть ли введенное пользователем число в списке Python

Tags: python

Я написал примерно такой код:

```py
x = [42, 8, 7, 1, 0, 124, 8897, 555, 3, 67, 99]
num = int (input())
if int (input) in x:
    print ('bingo')
```

Но при введении числа он ничего не выдает, кроме введенного числа.

Как сделать проверку есть ли число, которое ввели, в листе?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Опечатка в операторе `if`,потерялись скобки при вызове функции: должно быть `if int(input()) in x:`.  Но такой код приведёт к двойному вводу, так что вероятно подразумевалось `if num in x:`

Answer (score 6):

В условии не указана переменная `num`, поэтому оно не работает. Вот исправленный вариант:

```
x = [42, 8, 7, 1, 0, 124, 8897, 555, 3, 67, 99]
num = int (input())
if num in x:
    print ('bingo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы присваиваете введенное значение переменной `num`, поэтому нужно ее и включить в условие:

```py
if num in x:
    print('Bingo')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3 

def get_number(msg: str) -> int:
    """From user number."""

    try:
        line = input(msg)
        line_number = int(line)
        return line_number
    except ValueError as err:
        print(f'You entered uncorrect number -> {err}')
        get_number(msg) 
        

def is_valid(number: int, list_numbers: list) -> bool:
    """Testing number contains in list."""

    if number in list_numbers:
        return True
    return False

def main():
    message = 'Enter number -> '
    number = get_number(message)
    list_numbers = [i for i in range(100)]

    if is_valid(number, list_numbers) == True:
        print('Bingo!')
    else:
        print('Zero!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```